# kubespray k8s installation ends with NotReady worker node

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

im trying to install 3 node k8s cluster with kubespray-2.16.0 following https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray .
all the installation steps go fine, except this

```
TASK [kubernetes-apps/ansible : Kubernetes Apps | Register coredns deployment annotation `createdby`] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/local/bin/kubectl get deploy -n kube-system coredns -o jsonpath='{ .spec.template.metadata.annotations.createdby }'", "delta": "0:00:00.152435", "end": "2021-08-10 08:34:56.875744", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-08-10 08:34:56.723309", "stderr": "Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps \"coredns\" not found", "stderr_lines": ["Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps \"coredns\" not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
...ignoring
Tuesday 10 August 2021  08:34:56 +0000 (0:00:00.497)       0:10:30.178 ********
```

it finishes like this:

```
PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
node1                      : ok=568  changed=76   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1169 rescued=0    ignored=1
node2                      : ok=506  changed=73   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1015 rescued=0    ignored=0
node3                      : ok=425  changed=53   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=685  rescued=0    ignored=0
```

but when i check the status of the nodes after the installation, i can see that the (potentially) worker node is in notReady status.

```
[root@node1 kubespray-2.16.0]# kubectl get nodes -o=wide
NAME    STATUS     ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION               CONTAINER-RUNTIME
node1   Ready      control-plane,master   5m44s   v1.20.7   10.32.51.91   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.8
node2   Ready      control-plane,master   5m12s   v1.20.7   10.32.51.78   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.8
node3   NotReady   <none>                 4m1s    v1.20.7   10.32.51.61   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.8
[root@node1 kubespray-2.16.0]#


NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-7c5b64bf96-zkdcx   0/1     Pending            0          82s
calico-node-cdzgx                          1/1     Running            0          111s
calico-node-h5cz7                          0/1     Running            0          111s
calico-node-vpsch                          1/1     Running            0          111s
coredns-657959df74-lqpqw                   1/1     Running            0          41s
coredns-657959df74-qj6md                   1/1     Running            0          46s
dns-autoscaler-b5c786945-gvhff             1/1     Running            0          43s
kube-apiserver-node1                       1/1     Running            0          3m34s
kube-apiserver-node2                       1/1     Running            0          3m11s
kube-controller-manager-node1              1/1     Running            0          3m34s
kube-controller-manager-node2              1/1     Running            0          3m11s
kube-proxy-2pnf6                           1/1     Running            0          2m7s
kube-proxy-4sxp9                           1/1     Running            0          2m7s
kube-proxy-8mns8                           1/1     Running            0          2m7s
kube-scheduler-node1                       1/1     Running            0          3m34s
kube-scheduler-node2                       1/1     Running            0          3m11s
nginx-proxy-node3                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          2m13s
nodelocaldns-gvfst                         1/1     Running            0          42s
nodelocaldns-ktc89                         0/1     Pending            0          42s
nodelocaldns-vwtxn                         1/1     Running            0          42s
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-9pz4g   1/1     Running   0          68s
ingress-nginx-controller-lwb44   1/1     Running   0          68s
ingress-nginx-controller-sztht   0/1     Pending   0          68s
```

i checked the not running pods but as im newbie in k8s, i dont know which of them could be the rootcause and which nodes are just consequences.
could you please tell/help me what

1. could be the rootcause
2. how to investigate
3. and how to fix this issue?

i tried the installation at least 10x with different parameters, order of nodes, etc to debug, but the result was always the same.

thank you,
s.

Comment: FYI: installing and running

`yum install epel-release
yum install python-pip
pip install — upgrade pip
pip install -r requirements.txt`

instead of 

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

as it is recommended in https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray solved the issue. what's weird that no errors or warnings warned about this during the installation or the logs.